# build ros2 with c++11

Tags: ros, ros2, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a project written in c++11.

I would like to integrate a ros2 node in it.

Is there a way to build ros2 code with the c++11 flag instead of the c++14 one ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301326/build-ros2-with-c++11/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, ROS 2 relies on C++14 features, so it must be built with a compiler that supports C++14 and has it enabled (e.g. with `--std=c++14` or `--std=gnu++14`).

If you project builds with C++11 but your compiler supports C++14, then you can likely just build your C++11 based project with C++14 turned on and be fine.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2